# Electric capacitors instead of earthing electrode

Tags: capacitor, ground, grounding, capacitance, electrolytic-capacitor

I'm going to make a partial EM-shield (using aluminum) for my 3G USB (2.0) modem, and I need to "ground" electricity from the surface of that shield.

Daily **worktime** for that 3G modem is planned around 10 hours.

Calculations I made so far:

$$\text{USB (2.0) output} = 5_{\,V} * 0,5_{A} = 2,5_{\,W}$$
$$\text{Capacitance} = {\frac{2,5_{\,W} * 3600 \text{ (seconds) } * 10 \text{ (worktime) }}{{5_{\,V} * 5_{\,V}}}} = 3600_{\,F}$$

Meaning (if above is correct), that the surface of my shield may accumulate up to:

$$\text{Electric potential} = \sqrt{{\frac{2,5_{\,W} * 3600 \text{ (seconds) } * 10 \text{ (worktime) }}{{3600_{\,F}}}}} = 5_{\,V}$$

— which I need to "ground" daily.

**The problem is:** I'm living on a 6th floor of a many-apartment building built by the Soviet Union, and we do not have earthing electrode in our source circuit (like, seriously: we only have 2 wires inside each AC socket).

Sooo, since I'm *not* considering using metallic water pipes for my purpose - I thought of using **electric capacitors**.

I've read "out there" that such capacitors inside single domestic circuit (which will include that partially-shielded 3G modem, and my PC, and laptop, and monitor, and 2.1 sound system) - may effectively be used **instead** of loose-ended earthing electrode.

The question then (if that's true) is, how many capacitors do I need to "ground" 5 Volts daily; or, how much "Farads" their total capacitance should be?

I mean, these "daily" 3600 Farads I've calculated seems like an answer, but may have I missed something? Since there're NO capacitors on a market to maintain such capacitance: the best ones I found (*per a single device*, [like this one](https://www.flipkart.com/digiconnect-super-capacitor-100-farad-2-7-v-electronic-components-hobby-kit/p/itm3a7132d722abc)) consume only around 100-1000 Farads tops.

And (most importantly): will, say, 10 of such capacitors do their job if I'll dare to purchase them? I mean, how do they work anyway? Do they re-charge, or they will consume my 3600 Farads only once, and then immediately die?..

Additional data:

1. Devices I do have at a moment (PC, laptop, etc.) somehow do *not* have problems with extra-current on their surface, nor with electric shocks (so I felt like they're irrelevant for calculations).
2. Also (which probably *is* relevant): I'm going to cover a USB wire (connecting 3G modem) with aluminum foil, so the total usage of aluminum (which is, like, non-covered metal) is expected to be around 0,5-1 kg (1-2,2 lbs).

Comment: Why do you need to ‘ground’ the shield? Your calculations based on the USB power delivery are flawed and the results requiring the use of Farads are equally flawed. Show a picture of your shield and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Kartman but ain't my calculations based on a maximum output of a USB (2.0) socket? Only neglecting the stand-bys. And to picture verbally what I want to achieve is that I want to shield my Internet connector (and it's wires) from all directions, except **noiseless** clear patch of sky I have in my window.

Comment: The earth is relative to your 3g module not mains earth. Simply connecting the ‘shield’ to the shield of the usb cable should be sufficient.

Comment: @Kartman I don't understand: I thought all aluminum parts will accumulate electricity, which will not go away on itself. Are you saying that it will vanish without grounding (or capacitors) somehow?

Comment: Capacitors do not conduct DC and your calculations only use DC therefore false logic

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 that's new (for a 2nd-3rd day into that stuff). So, no alternative?

Comment: Your main concern should be static electricity. Apart from that just connect it to the shield of the usb cable. Don’t apply the wrong theory to the wrong problem.

Comment: It's just my wrong impression :) But I'll gladly improve it! Thanks!

Comment: Is the 3G USB modem plugged into an AC to DC adaptor connected to a power outlet, or is it connected to the USB port of a computer? Either way, why do you want a *partial* EM shield if the manufacturer doesn't specify it?

Comment: If the AC to DC adaptor and the 3G modem doesn't have metallic parts in its outer body,  and if the manufacturer hasn't provided any earth pin to the AC to DC adaptor, then the device is not intended to be used with any grounding. Why did you conclude that charges may be accumulating on the device surface?

Comment: Your second formula seems to be just *undoing* the first formula. You will always get 5V irrespective of the current draw and working duration if you apply the formulae as it is shown above IMO.

Comment: @AJN well, partial is because my straightforward guess was that full shielded modem will seize to work, won't it?.. And, yes: the wire goes into USB port on my PC or laptop directly. As for another guess on a need in '*grounding*' the shield... well, aluminum is highly conductive, which mean free electrons; and electrons become excited with waves, which highly interact with shield, so I figured that there'll be electricity. And in worst case - it should be proportional to max output of USB (2.0).

Comment: Under normal working condition, the charges entering the device via the live wire (phase for AC or V+ for USB DC) are automatically drained via the return (neutral for AC or gnd for USB DC) wire. No charge accumulation that needs to be drained. (Other than static charge mentioned in a comment above)

Comment: @AJN that's yet again helpful, thank you! And commenters above.

Comment: @VictorNovak why are you trying to do this? .... what is the actual problem that you are seeing? ... not a problem that somebody said you have

Comment: @jsotola as I commented above, my problem is the **noise**!

Comment: Why do you need to partially shield your modem...? If it is interfering with some other device, you may be able to move it further away.

Comment: @user253751 I tried.

Answer (score 4):

You have calculated the amount of capacitance required to *store* 25 Wh at 5 V. But the energy drawn by the USB MODEM is not stored, it is *dissipated* (mostly as heat, with a little transmitted rf.). You don't have to worry about this electricity because it is *consumed* by the MODEM.

It *is* possible for a metal surface to build up a static charge if it is not 'earthed', but its capacitance is determined by its size and distance from the earth or nearest circuit connected to it. For a non-earthed mains powered device such as a laptop the largest parasitic capacitance is between the primary and secondary windings of the power supply transformer, which is usually only a few hundred picofarads.

However a larger capacitor is usually added between the primary and secondary sides to reduce EMI. This capacitor 'shorts out' the EMI on the secondary side to reduce its voltage. To do the job well it should have a much larger capacitance than the transformer windings, but not too large or sufficient AC mains voltage could leak through to give a noticeable electric shock. Typical values are 1~2.2 nF. With this small capacitance static charge could easily produce several thousand volts if not discharged, so power supplies often have a high value 'bleeder' resistor across the capacitor to discharge it. A resistance of several megohms is high enough to prevent electric shock but low enough to discharge the capacitor in less than a second.

As an example, [here's](https://obrazki.elektroda.pl/8550037800_1392113427.gif) (part of) the schematic of a Dell laptop power supply:-

[image]

C006 has a value of 1 nF, and the 5 resistors have a total series resistance of 50 MΩ. Both are connected from the primary (mains voltage) side of the switch-mode power supply to the secondary (low voltage output) side, providing a weak 'ground' at DC and a stronger 'ground' at low to medium rf frequencies. This is not a 'true' ground because it is not connected directly to mains earth, but it is close enough for EMI suppression purposes.

If your device's power supply has a similar circuit then there is no need to worry about grounding the USB MODEM because it is already sufficiently grounded through the USB port.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to secure your computer Internet's 3G access from local hackers by using;

> "aluminum foil, so the total usage of aluminum (which is, like, non-covered metal) is expected to be around 0,5-1 kg" and pointing the antenna up in the sky out the window.

The USB is wired so it is not radiating.

I think your idea of security solution is not realistic, or scientific. Your WIFI does not bounce from the sky.  It does bounce off all buildings.

This would be like trying build a dirty bomb shelter for nerve gas but still have the window open.

Comment: I thought of that, but for the 1st try I'm hoping that wavelength of 3G (14 sm) would somehow enter that "window". Will see about that, 1 step at a time, of course. As for "the shelter"... well, if anyone interfered with me like that, and none of boundaries I've put had worked - I'd prefer to force *these* in such shelter, just enough for me to never be bothered.